# Refresh the score automatically every 30 seconds through code and without 'Refresh' button

Tags: javascript, php

I have a index.php file where I am displaying cricket score:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

echo '<br/>';

$content=file_get_contents("http://cricscore-api.appspot.com/csa?id=1062576");

$array = json_decode($content,true);

echo $array[0]['de'];

header('Refresh:10;URL=index.php');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getReply(data) {
    document.getElementById("displayScore").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("displayScore").innerHTML+=data.match+"<br/>";
    document.getElementById("displayScore").innerHTML+=data.score+"<br/>";
    document.getElementById("displayScore").innerHTML+=data.summary+"<br/>";    
    document.getElementById("displayScore").innerHTML+="Dt: "+data.date+"<br/>";    
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json?callback=getReply"></script>
```

I want the score to be refreshed automatically every 30 seconds through code without having any Refresh button in the page.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using Javascript to reload the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function() {
    document.location = "http://YOUR_APP_URL";
   }, 30000);
  //other code as usual
</script>
```

If you want to make your app better you can use `AJAX`

Comment: Sir, I am not getting where actually to place this code. Just before the function 'function getReply(data) {' ?

Comment: yes sir.. just place it before function getReply(data) {

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
}, 30000
);
</script>
```

or:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

in your `<head>` tag

as Hari Lamichhane said If you want to make your app better you can use AJAX

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer